# Jquery : remove element in form from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove element in form, it is working ok, only problem the user must click twice to remove element, after that all is working fine, only first time user must click twice any ideas, or similar problem?

Here is my code

```
function deleteParentElement(){
             $(".remove-button").click(function(event) {
             $(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
               return false; 
            });                  
        }
```

Here HTML

```
<div class="input-group has-delete">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input yellow" value="" name="license_plates[' + rowCount + ']" id="license_plate">
            <button class="btn btn-input  remove-button" onclick="deleteParentElement();" type="button"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `onclick="deleteParentElement();"` and execute `deleteParentElement` on DOMReady!

Comment: Well that‘s because you are using one click handler (via `onclick` attribute) here to assign a second clickhandler ... So of course that second handler can only fire on subsequent clicks, because it simply has not been assigned on the first click.

Comment: This is how it works
 function deleteParentElement(element){
      $(element).parents('.has-delete').remove();
                  return false; 
            }

onclick="deleteParentElement(this);

Answer (score 2):

- Remove inline event handler
- Invoke the function on `$(document).ready`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".remove-button").click(function(event) {
    $(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group has-delete">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input yellow" value="" name="license_plates[' + rowCount + ']" id="license_plate">
      <button class="btn btn-input  remove-button" type="button"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**If elements are dynamically added, use** `Event delegation`**,**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('click', '.remove-button', function(event) {
    $(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group has-delete">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input yellow" value="" name="license_plates[' + rowCount + ']" id="license_plate">
      <button class="btn btn-input  remove-button" type="button"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work, because element is added by user

Answer (score 1):

In you function, you're attaching a click event listener, which when triggered will remove the parent element, you should be removing the element directly.

```
function deleteParentElement(){
    $(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
}
```

But this is still the incorrect way to apply such an event handler. You can remove the `deleteParentElement` function and achieve the same result like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* your code */

    $(".remove-button").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents(".has-delete").remove()
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you write teh full answe

Comment: The problem is that element is now shown on the page, it can by added by another function addElement

Comment: I've edited to answer to be clearer. @MiomirDancevic if you wanted to add more elements, but remove them in the same way, then this code will still work.

Comment: If you can post a JSFiddle of your code, I can take a look at what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="input-group has-delete">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input yellow" value="" name="license_plates[' + rowCount + ']" id="license_plate">
            <button class="btn btn-input  remove-button"  type="button"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
 $(".remove-button").click(function(event) {
             $(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
               return false; 
            });  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so obvious because you are calling an onClick function inside which you are registering an event handler for click again. So, remove onclick and just register the click on DOM Ready event.

```
<button class="btn btn-input  remove-button">

          $(".remove-button").click(function(event) {
             $(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
               return false; 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you click on the button, your `deleteParentElement` function executes which attaches a click event-handler to the element. **It does not execute the code inside now.** Now that an click event-handler has been attached, the next time you click it, the code inside `$(".remove-button").click(function(event)` executes and your element gets removed.

There are two solutions to your problem.

***Solution-1***
Edit your script to this

```
function deleteParentElement(){
$(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
```

}

***Solution-2***
Edit your HTML to this

```
            <button class="btn btn-input  remove-button" type="button"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
```

and your script to this

```
$(".remove-button").click(function(event) {
         $(this).parents('.has-delete').remove();
           return false; 
        });
```